# Twisted Python - How to create list of acceptableCiphers for CertificateOptions?

Tags: python, encryption, twisted

I'm struggling to create a list of iCipher objects to pass into my ssl.CertificateOptions as my acceptableCiphers. I want to pass in a comma separated list of strings (cipher names) and build the cipher list from there. Something like:

```
from twisted.internet._sslverify import OpenSSLCipher
cipherList = "KRB5-IDEA-CBC-SHA,SEED-SHA"
mySupportedCiphers = []
for cipher in cipherList.split(","):
                    mySupportedCiphers.append(OpenSSLCipher(cipher))
```

....
    myCertOpts = ssl.CertificateOptions(acceptableCiphers = mySupportedCiphers)

Alternatively / additionally, a means of returning the names of the default / full list of ciphers supported by the TLS implementation in use, as per the [Twisted Docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IAcceptableCiphers.html)

My apologies if this sounds vague - we're trying to establish why my mail receiver can successfully connect over TLS with one of our systems, but not another... Looks like it's cipher related, but my understanding is admittedly limited, so we (I!) am sort of exploring....

Thanks as always! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [`AcceptableCiphers`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.ssl.AcceptableCiphers.html)`.fromOpenSSLCipherString` constructor.

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import AcceptableCiphers

cipherListString = "KRB5-IDEA-CBC-SHA,SEED-SHA".replace(",", ":")

acceptableCiphers = AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString(cipherListString)

options = CertificateOptions(..., acceptableCiphers=acceptableCiphers)
```

Comment: I've not tried it yet, but I trust you well enough by now @Jean-PaulCalderone ;-) looks exactly what I was looking for, thank you!